Почему MSHTA не запускаеться
Может не по теме сайта но у меня есть проблема, когда я запускаю .hta файл ругаеться "эта программа не может роботать на вашем пк", а когда ставлю mshta.exe на открытие .hta файла, то ошибки про то что я не могу поставить эту программу на этот файл.
что делать?
